# Can't get Landsat-8 images after 2017-06-01 in Google Earth Engine Python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, landsat-8

Using the Google Earth Engine Python API, I can get a Landsat-8 TOA image for anytime before 2017-06-01 but not for any dates after that.

Getting a Landsat-8 TOA image for before 2017-06-01:

---

```
from IPython.display import Image
import ee
ee.Initialize()

landsat8_collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA')
   .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-01-30')
   .first()

landsat8_collection.getInfo()
```

Getting an output:

```
{'type': 'Image', 'bands': [{'id': 'B1', 'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'float'}, 'dimensions': [8201, 8281], 'crs': 'EPSG:32623', 'crs_transform':...
```

Then, when I try to get an image for anytime after 2017-06-01 I get no output:

```
landsat8_collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA')
     .filterDate('2017-06-01', '2017-06-30')
     .first()

landsat8_collection.getInfo()
```

Getting no output:

```
None
```

I can obtain images for after 2017-06-01 through the JavaScript interface in Google Earth Engine, but for some reason not using the Python client. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an old Earth Engine collection: `'LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA'`. The new collection is `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA`.

```
new_l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')\
           .filterDate('2017-06-01', '2017-06-30')

print(new_l8.size().getInfo())

# returns 13658
```

[image]